# (q/kdb+) Update rows using results from previous rows

Tags: kdb

Using the table

```
t:([]c1: 3 4 7 2 4.0;c2: 2 8 10 1 9.0;c3:5 8 13 2 11.0)

c1  c2  c3
3   2   5
4   8   8
7   10  13
2   1   2
4   9   11
```

I need to update 3 new columns `(c1M,c2M,c3M)` where:

- for the first row:

  - `c1M:avg(c1,c2,c3)`
  - `c2M:avg(c1,c2)`
  - `c3M:c3`
- other rows:

  - `c1M:avg(c1,c2,c3)`
  - `c2M:avg(prev c1M,prev c2M)`
  - `c3M:max(c3,c1M,c2M)`

I can do first row using

```
t:update c1M:avg(c1,c2,c3),c2M:avg(c1,c2),c3M:c3 from t where i=0

c1  c2  c3  c1M c2M c3M
3   2   5   3.3 2.5 5
4   8   8   0n  0n  0N
7   10  13  0n  0n  0N
2   1   2   0n  0n  0N
4   9   11  0n  0n  0N
```

Not sure how to proceed tough. I tried something like:

```
update c1M:avg(c1;c2;c3),c2M:avg(prev c1M;prev c2M),c3M:c3|c1M|c2M from t where i>0
```

But no luck.

The result for this example should be:

```
c1  c2  c3  c1M c2M c3M
3   2   5   3.3 2.5 5.0
4   8   8   6.7 2.9 8.0
7   10  13  10  4.8 13.0
2   1   2   1.7 7.4 7.4
4   9   11  8.0 4.5 11.0
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is over:
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#over

It will iterate through each row of the table

```
q)({update c3M:max(c3;c1M;c2M),c2M:c2M^avg(prev c1M;prev c2M),c1M:c1M^avg(c1;c2;c3) from x}/)[update c1M:avg(c1,c2,c3),c2M:avg(c1,c2),c3M:c3 from t where i=0] 
c1 c2 c3 c1M c2M c3M
--------------------
3  2  5  3.3 2.5 5  
4  8  8  6.7 2.9 8  
7  10 13 10  4.8 13 
2  1  2  1.7 7.4 7.4
4  9  11 8   4.5 11
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the use of `^`? Is it to return the value itself?

Comment: ^ is fill, it will replace a null avg(prev c1M;prev c2M) value with c2M for example: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#fill

Answer (score 5):

KDB+ is much faster at vector calculations than it is at iteration. Because of this, a possible faster way to do this is to iterate only over the c2M column using an adverb, as it is the only one that requires the previous value from the column.
I think what you may be looking for is:

```
update c3M:c3 from (update c3M:max(c3;c1M;c2M) from update c2M:{avg x,y}\[first 
c2;first[c1],1_prev c1M] from update c1M:avg(c1;c2;c3) from t) where i=0
```

This runs faster than iterating and performing calculations over the whole table, like so:

```
q)\ts:1000 ({update c3M:max(c3;c1M;c2M),c2M:c2M^avg(prev c1M;prev 
c2M),c1M:c1M^avg(c1;c2;c3) from x}/)[update 
c1M:avg(c1,c2,c3),c2M:avg(c1,c2),c3M:c3 from t where i=0]
53 7568

q)\ts:1000 update c3M:c3 from (update c3M:max(c3;c1M;c2M) from update c2M: 
{avg x,y}\[first c2;first[c1],1_prev c1M] from update c1M:avg(c1;c2;c3) from 
t) where i=0
11 6896
```

Answer (score 1):

```
q) nt:update c1m:avg(c1;c2;c3) from t 
q) nt:update c2m:-1_({avg x,y}\[avg[c1[0],c2[0]],c1m]) from nt
q) nt:update c3m:(c3[0],1_max(c3;c1m;c2m)) from nt
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, likely not the fastest but a smaller code footprint

```
q){y,`c1M`c2M`c3M!a,max y[`c3],a:(avg y;avg y[`c1`c2]^x`c1M`c2M)}\[t@-1;t]
c1 c2 c3 c1M      c2M      c3M
-----------------------------------
3  2  5  3.333333 2.5      5
4  8  8  6.666667 2.916667 8
7  10 13 10       4.791667 13
2  1  2  1.666667 7.395833 7.395833
4  9  11 8        4.53125  11
```

Comment: Can you give me a quick explanation on the structure?

Comment: It takes a blank row as the seed (`t@-1`) - this allows for modifying the behaviour of the first run since the initial logic is different - and scans through each row of t. Inside the function `x` represents the previously created row (or the blank on the first run) and `y` represents the next row of c1, c2 and c3. Then you can perform the necessary logic to get the averages and max and append the c1M, c2M and c3M to the c1, c2 and c3. This result gets passed back into the function as the new `x` until all `y`'s (i.e. all rows from t) are processed

Comment: Oh and it's worth mentioning that the inputs and outputs to the function are dictionaries so since all of the output dictionaries conform to the same shape, kdb automatically converts to a table (a table is a list of dictionaries)